# What is the difference between 'dependencies' and 'framework dependencies' in project.json?

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

What is the difference between load a package in `dependencies` or `framework dependencies`?

And... Is possible use only dnxcore50 nowadays? (asp.net 5 beta6)

**dependencies:**

```
{
  "description": "Lib",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta6"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
    }
  }
}
```

**framework dependencies:**

```
{
  "description": "Lib",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
          "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta6"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dependencies` are for all frameworks listed under `frameworks`. `dependencies` under a specific framework for that specific framework. This means that you can pull **dependency A** for **framework X** but not for **framework Z** if you want to.

Comment: so if I have just one framework in my project.json, both 'dependencies' are the same?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. The framework specific dependencies is only useful when you have multiple frameworks and you want different dependencies for each of them